# How to in Json.NET retrieve a few values in a large file as fast as possible?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I need to display a list of Json files. Each file contains a pretty big object that will take a while to serialize. In total the performance hit of serializing every single object takes too much time when I just want to display a list of them. The file looks somewhat like this:

```
{
    'Name': 'File Name',
    'Version': '1.6',
    'BigLongToSerializeObject': {/* The big object here */}
}
```

How can I retrieve only `Name` and `Version` from this file as efficiently as possible in Json.NET?

Comment: Apply the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to the model that holds these fields and it won't deserialize it.

Comment: I do have to deserialize it eventually, just when it's displaying a list it shouldn't yet.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/04/15/conditionally-serializing-fields-and-properties-with-jsonnet)?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can route information to such a method. Also does changing the model to have that be ignored improve the speed of serialization if I don't need that field? If yes I could just make a different model that lacks this property.

Comment: Yes, JSON.NET will skip that field if you decide it should be ignored so that will improve the speed. As to your last remark: that is indeed a way to solve this. In fact, I have recently written [an answer on CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69654/21028) that discusses this scenario, you might be interested in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize your deserialization via custom ContractResolver.

Create contract resolver

```
class ListContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(
                        Type type, 
                        MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var result = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        if(/*type is your type*/)
            result = result.Where(i=>i.PropertyName != "BigLongToSerializeObject")
                           .ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then create serializer for list deserializing

```
 var listSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
 serializer.ContractResolver = new ListContractResolver ();
```

then you can use `listSerializer` to deserialize list and use default serializer to deserialize normally.

Comment: Would adding a method `ShouldSerialize` as @Jeroen-Vannevel said not easier then creating a new class?

Answer (score 0):

[JSON# has a very lightweight tool](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/11/21/json-tutorial-1-returning-embedded-objects/) that allows you to achieve this. It will retrieve embedded JSON from within larger JSON objects:

```
const string schoolMetadata = @"{ "school": {...";
var jsonParser = new JsonObjectParser();

using (var stream = 
    new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(schoolMetadata))) {
    Json.Parse(_jsonParser, stream, "teachers");
}
```

Here we retrieve a "teachers" object from within a larger "school" object.